# Mac OSx Lion - Cannot get RoR installed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I recently upgraded to Lion and I am trying to install Rails. I used RubyGems to install rails and each time I tried to start a new rails project I would get an error saying, "Method 'list ' was not found".

So I unistalled Rails using RubyGems. I noticed I had two versions installed. I uninstalled both. I then ran 'gem clean'. Once again I installed Rails but now when I attempt to create a new rails application it's as if rails is not installed.

> rails: command not found

I have the new Xcode command line tools installed. Can anyone help a brother out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe my issue is due to the fact RubyGem does not add 'rails' to the $PATH environment variable. I was able to get everything working by installing [RVM](https://rvm.io/rvm/install/) and using it to update my default Ruby and install Rails